# R Frechet Quantile plot

Tags: r, plot, quantile

I have a vector with a single column of data (axle weights of vehicles) for which I need to create a Frechet Quantile (Q-Q) plot in R. The library qualityTools doesn't deal with this distribution. How do I create a Q-Q plot for the Frechet distribution in R? I have tried the following without success:

```
x<-T4A4$X79
y<-sort(x,decreasing=FALSE)
View(y)
vectorlength=length(y)
View(vectorlength)

d=dfrechet(y,shape=1)
p=pfrechet(y,shape=1)
q=qfrechet(p,shape=1)

View(d)
View(p)
View(q)
plot(q,y,main="Frechet")
```

Answer (score 0):

[This web page](http://data.library.virginia.edu/understanding-q-q-plots/) shows one way. Here is how:

```
your_data <- rnorm(30)
qqplot(x = VGAM::qfrechet(ppoints(n = length(your_data)), 
                          shape = 1),
       y = your_data,
       xlab = "Theoretical Quantiles", 
       ylab = "Sample Quantiles")
```